# CV_8U opencv's matrixes on no 8 bit systems

Tags: opencv

I've read that the signed char and unsigned char types are not guaranteed to be 8 bits on every platform, but sometimes they have more than 8 bits.
If so, using OpenCv how can we be sure that CV_8U is always 8bit?
I've written a short function which takes a 8 bit Mat and happens to convert, if needed, CV_8SC1 Mat elements into uchars and CV_8UC1 into schar.
Now I'm afraid it is not platform independent an I should fix the code in some way (but don't know how).

P.S.: Similarly, how can CV_32S always be int, also on machine with no 32bit ints?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about this - just let OpenCV take care of the underlying implementation. Platforms with CHAR_BIT > 8 are somewhat unusual (typically DSPs). sizeof(int) > 4 is somewhat more common, but I'm pretty sure OpenCV will handle this.

Comment: Actually OpenCV is promised to work only on ia32, amd64 and arm (since 2.3.0) platforms. All these platforms have 8 bit char and 32bit int.

Comment: @AndreyKamaev. And as to schar to uchar conversion and viceversa, do you think that can I rely on the code I've written? Are all those platform complement 2?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a reference of this (I've never heard of that)? Probably you mean the padding that may be added at the end of a row in a cv::Mat. That is of no problem, since the padding is usually not used, and especially no problem if you use the interface functions, e.g. the iterators ([c.f.](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html)). If you would post some code, we could see, if your implementation actually had such problems.

```
// template methods for iteration over matrix elements.
// the iterators take care of skipping gaps in the end of rows (if any)
template<typename _Tp> MatIterator_<_Tp> begin();
template<typename _Tp> MatIterator_<_Tp> end();
```

the `CV_32S` will be always 32-bit integer because they use types like those defined in `inttypes.h` (e.g. `int32_t`, `uint32_t`) and not the platform specific `int`, `long`, whatever.